Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Int?>'
I am developing a SwiftUI carrousel that needs to display images using pagination. For iPhone the scrolling is horizontal and for iPad the scrolling is vertical.
On iOS 17, the scrollPosition was introduced, but, since our project needs to support iOS 14, my current solution is that one.
final class GalleryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentIndex = 0

}

struct GalleryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: GalleryViewModel

    var body: some View {
        if isPhone {
            TabView(selection: $viewModel.currentIndex) {
                ForEach(Array(viewModel.mediaItems.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, element in
                    makeSomeItemView(
                        item: element,
                        index: index
                    )
                    .tag(index)
                }
            }
        } else {
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    ScrollView(.vertical) {
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(Array(viewModel.mediaItems.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, element in
                                makeSomeItemView(
                                    item: element,
                                    index: index
                                )
                                .frame(
                                    width: proxy.size.width,
                                    height: proxy.size.height
                                )
                                .id(element)
                            }
                        }
                        .scrollTargetLayout()
                    }
                    .scrollIndicators(.never)
                    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                    .scrollPosition(id: $viewModel.currentSelection)
                }
            } else {
                VerticalTabView(selection: $viewModel.currentIndex) {
                    ForEach(Array(viewModel.MediaItems.enumerated()), id: \.1) { index, element in
                        makeSomeItemView(
                            item: element,
                            index: index
                        )
                        .tag(index)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public struct VerticalTabView<Content: View, SelectionValue: Hashable>: View {
    private var selection: Binding<SelectionValue>?
    private var content: () -> Content

    public init(
        selection: Binding<SelectionValue>?,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.selection = selection
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                TabView(selection: selection) {
                    content()
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                        .frame(
                            width: proxy.size.width,
                            height: proxy.size.height
                        )
                }
                .frame(
                    width: proxy.size.height,
                    height: proxy.size.width
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(90), anchor: .topLeading)
                .offset(x: proxy.size.width)
                .tabViewStyle(
                    PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

The issue is TabView uses Binding<Int> and Scroll View uses Binding<Int?>
Any ideas how to solve it?

You can try this solution: declaring an internal Binding<Int?> by wrapping viewModel.currentIndex then bind it to .scrollPosition
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    let binding: Binding<Int?> = .init { //<- here
        viewModel.currentIndex
    } set: { newValue in
        viewModel.currentIndex = newValue ?? 0
    }
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            ...
        }
        .scrollPosition(id: binding)
    }
}
...


You could use a computed binding for this:
// GalleryView

private var currentSelection: Binding<Int?> {
    Binding<Int?>(
        get: { viewModel.currentIndex },
        set: { newVal in
            viewModel.currentIndex = newVal ?? 0
        }
    )
}

ScrollView(.vertical) {
    // ...
}
.scrollPosition(id: currentSelection)

